# Access abstract class members from childs inherits

Tags: c#, .net

I have an abstract class called Flight and its implement a interface called IFlight and it has a virtual method, another three classes that inherit from it, the only diffrence between those three classes is the implemantation of this method. Another thing that I want to do is implement a method that accepts as an argument an object of type IFlight (could be one of those three classes) and from them i want to access the members of the abstract class (Flight). Which way there is to implement such thing ?

Flight:

```
class AbsFlight: IFlight
{ 
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Start_Point { get; set; }

    public virtual float Calculate_Price(float Base_Price)
    {
        return Base_Price;
    } 
}
```

One of the classes (The other two looks similar except the method "Calculate_Price"):

```
class Charter: AbsFlight
{
    public override float Calculate_Price(float Base_Price)
    {
        return base.Calculate_Price(Base_Price) * 3;
    }
}
```

Main:

```cs
private static void Some_Method(IFlight flight)
{
    Console.WriteLine(flight.Calculate_Price(2)); //OK
    Console.WriteLine(flight.ID); //Error
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<IFlight> flights = new List<IFlight>();

    flights.Add(new Regular());
    flights.Add(new Charter());
    flights.Add(new LowCost());

    Main_SomeMethod(flights[0]);
}
```

Comment: so either a) move `ID` to your `IFlight` interface or b) use reflection

Comment: @zaitsman So if i move it to the interface than i have to implement them in the abs class ? (I have about 15 variables in the real app)

Comment: Your problem is you have an instance which `Some_Method` knows nothing about. It just knows that whatever is passed in is implementing an interface. You can cast your type to specific type, use reflection or add this requirement to the interface. Tbh it seels lik a possible X-Y problem or something missing from your question

Comment: Why do you mix abstract class and interface? Since C# 8  you can define [default implementation inside your interface](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/). So, basically there is no need for the abstract class.

Comment: So, you want to accept `IFlight` but access members from `AbsFlight`? What would you do if the object is not an `AbsFlight`?  If it is guaranteed to be an `AbsFlight`, why not simply make that the type instead of `IFlight`

Comment: @JonasH Because i have a List<IFlight> that could have object of three classes type, i didn't knew I could create a list of AbsFlight ..

Comment: You could use a `List<AbsFlight>`, but you are probably better of with a `IEnumerable<AbsFlight>`. The later will accept a `List<MyDerivedAbsFlight>`, while the former will not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current solution, in combination with some of the suggestions, will be a case of a **mounted riding rider**. You don't need an interface *and* a base class *and* testing for type.

You *can* solve your problem the way you're trying, with a base class and an interface. But it's overkill, and you have to kind of duplicate some stuff in the interface and the base class.

You can solve your problem with a simple base class and three derived classes where only Calculate_Price gets overridden. Put the common items in the base class. This is a very simple solution, easy to figure out, especially if C# and OOP is new to you.

You can also solve your problem with an interface and three classes, not derived. This has the disadvantage that you have to implement the interface in three classes. As Peter Csala points out, C# 8 has some language features that can help minimize this work, possibly making this just as simple as using only a base class and no interface. I am not too familiar with those features, so I can't judge whether it makes sense.

Then there is another option entirely. This touches on what zaitsman hinted at - that this is possibly an XY problem. Why do you want to distinguish between Regular, Charter and LowCost using classes derived from Flight/AbsFlight? Is it possible to just have an attribute that tells what price profile is used? Are there other fields and properties of a Flight that has nothing to do with the price, and yet also distinguishes flights? Perhaps just use one class.

About testing for class type. This is what we call code smell. Generally, if you test for class types a lot, then you defy the purpose of using classes and/or interfaces in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Your method should accept the type that has the properties it needs, in this case the `AbsFlight` class.

```
private static void Some_Method(AbsFlight flight)
{
    Console.WriteLine(flight.Calculate_Price(2)); 
    Console.WriteLine(flight.ID); //OK
}
```

But let's says the method *must* accept any `IFlight`. In this case, it can't be sure it received an AbsFlight; it has to check. After the check you can just cast.

```
private static void Some_Method(IFlight flight)
{
    Console.WriteLine(flight.Calculate_Price(2)); 
    if (flight is AbsFlight)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(((AbsFlight)flight).ID); //OK
    }
}
```

With c#7 there is an additional construct you can use, if you think it is clearer:

```
private static void Some_Method(IFlight flight)
{
    Console.WriteLine(flight.Calculate_Price(2)); 
    switch (flight)
    {
        case AbsFlight absFlight:
            Console.WriteLine(absFlight.ID); //OK
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be that you are doing something wrong that this is your requirement.

When you use an interface and pass it as an argument you want it to be common to all the objects that implement it.

Anyway, if you do want to do it. You might do something like:

```
if (flight is Flight)
{
    Flight yourFlight = (Flight)flight;
    // Here you can use anything you need from Flight, e.g: yourFlight.ID
}
```